# Regex search with nested AND-Query in OR-query

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm currently implementing a search-Functionality with the help of regular expressions (I cannot use fulltext-Search because I'm already using the $near functionality in the same query).

A query can look something like this:

```
"restaurant vegan"
```

I have two attributes ("title" and "description").

I want to return documents where the title or the description should match the query in any order.

something like this:

```
(title is 'restaurant' and title is 'vegan') or (description is 'restaurant' and description is 'vegan')
```

I have already implemented a code which uses caption groups but MongoDB doesn't support caption groups yet.

```
{ "$or":
  [
    { "title" : { "$regex" : "/(?=.*restaurant)(?=.*vegan)/i" } },
    { "description" : { "$regex" : "/(?=.*restaurant)(?=.*vegan)/i" } }
  ]
}
```

Here are some sample documents:

```
{
  _id: 'dskladkaskdlsakldas'
  title: 'Nice restaurant',
  description: 'Eat fresh, eat vegan'
},
{
  _id: 'dsjkaskdsakdjsak',
  title: 'Cooking nice stuff',
  description: 'Vegan cooking with great people'
}
```

Comment: can you post your documents?

Comment: Thank you. I just posted some sample documents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

```
var reg = /\bvegan\b|\brestaurant\b/i;   

db.collection.find({ 
    $or: 
        [
            { title: reg},
            { description: reg }
        ]
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

assumoing youre looking for ((title contains restaurant AND title contains vegan) OR (description contains restaurant AND description contains vegan)), which does not correspond to your example document but seems much more logic, you could simply:

> { "$or":   [
>
> ```
> { "$and": 
>
>   [
>
>     { "title" : { "$regex" : "/restaurant/i" } },
>     { "title" : { "$regex" : "/vegan/i" } }
>   ]
> },
> { "$and": 
>   [
>     { "description" : { "$regex" : "/restaurant/i" } },
>     { "description" : { "$regex" : "/vegan/i" } }
>   ]
> }   ] }
> ```

but if it's OR everywhere:

```
db.test.find({ "$or":   [
  { "title" : { "$regex" : /restaurant/i } },
  { "title" : { "$regex" : /vegan/i } },
  { "description" : { "$regex" : /restaurant/i } },
  { "description" : { "$regex" : /vegan/i } }
 ] });
```

not much more difficult is it?

Comment: How is this better than existing solution?

Comment: Hello Michael, well it's not, it's just different, using more mongo and less regex.

Comment: you use **four** times `$regex` :P

Comment: yes :-D
of course I mean more complexity on mongo and less in regex.